# OpenXml is overwriting existing worksheets

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, openxml

I am trying to add worksheets to an existing workbook.  The existing Excel file will already have at least one worksheet.  My problem is that the code below just overwrites existing worksheets in the excel file.  How can I change the code below to add new worksheets without overwriting any existing worksheets

I am new to openxml, so I am unsure of where I went wrong.

```
                using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
                {
                    List<OpenXmlAttribute> oxa;
                    OpenXmlWriter oxw;

                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = xl.WorkbookPart;
                    //xl.AddWorkbookPart();
                    WorksheetPart wsp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

                    oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(wsp);
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

                    for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum <= arrExport.Count - 1; rowNum++)
                    {
                        int u = Convert.ToInt32(rowNum.ToString());
                        oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("r", null, "str"));

                        oxw.WriteStartElement(new Row(), oxa);
                        int NextPosition = 0;
                        for (int col = 0; col < arrExport[u].ColumnData.Count; col++)
                        {
                            if (!((col + 1) >= arrExport[u].ColumnData.Count - 1))
                            {
                                NextPosition = (arrExport[u].ColumnData[col + 1].ColumnNumber - arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnNumber);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                NextPosition = arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnNumber - 1;
                            }

                            for (int x = 0; x < NextPosition; x++)
                            {
                                oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                                // this is the data type ("t"), with CellValues.String ("str")
                                oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));

                                oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
                                oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(""));

                                // this is for Cell
                                oxw.WriteEndElement();
                            }
                            oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                            // this is the data type ("t"), with CellValues.String ("str")
                            oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));


                            oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
                            oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnData.ToString() == null ? "" : arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnData.ToString()));

                            // this is for Cell
                            oxw.WriteEndElement();


                        }

                        // this is for Row
                        oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    }

                    // this is for SheetData
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    // this is for Worksheet
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    oxw.Close();

                    oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(xl.WorkbookPart);
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Workbook());
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Sheets());

                    oxw.WriteElement(new Sheet()
                    {
                        Name = "Sheet" + sheetnumber.ToString(),
                        SheetId = Convert.ToUInt32(sheetnumber),
                        Id = xl.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wsp)
                    });

                    // this is for Sheets
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    // this is for Workbook
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    oxw.Close();

                    xl.Close();
                }
```

I expect existing worksheets in the excel file to remain, and a new worksheet added.

EDIT: Updated code-

```
          if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
                {
                    List<OpenXmlAttribute> oxa;
                    OpenXmlWriter oxw;
                    SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart;
                    if (xl.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        shareStringPart = xl.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        shareStringPart = xl.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
                    }

                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = xl.WorkbookPart;   //xl.AddWorkbookPart();
                    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                    Sheets objSheets = new Sheets();
                    workbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));
                    workbookPart.Workbook.Append(objSheets);

                    //xl.AddWorkbookPart();
                    WorksheetPart wsp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    String strWorkSheetPartId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
                    wsp.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

                    SheetData objSheetData = new SheetData();
                    Sheet objSheet = new Sheet() { Name = "Sheet" + sheetnumber.ToString(), SheetId = (UInt32Value)1U, Id = strWorkSheetPartId };
                    //wsp.Worksheet = objSheet;
                    objSheets.Append(objSheet);

                    //oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(wsp);
                    //oxw.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                    //oxw.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

                    //for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum <= arrExport.Count - 1; rowNum++)
                    //{
                    //    int u = Convert.ToInt32(rowNum.ToString());
                    //    oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                    //    oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("r", null, "str"));

                    //    //oxw.WriteStartElement(new Row(), oxa);
                    //    int NextPosition = 0;
                    //    for (int col = 0; col < arrExport[u].ColumnData.Count; col++)
                    //    {
                    //        if (!((col + 1) >= arrExport[u].ColumnData.Count - 1))
                    //        {
                    //            NextPosition = (arrExport[u].ColumnData[col + 1].ColumnNumber - arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnNumber);

                    //        }
                    //        else
                    //        {
                    //            NextPosition = arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnNumber - 1;
                    //        }

                    //        for (int x = 0; x < NextPosition; x++)
                    //        {
                    //            oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                    //            // this is the data type ("t"), with CellValues.String ("str")
                    //            oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));

                    //            //oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
                    //            //oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(""));

                    //            // this is for Cell
                    //           // oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    //        }
                    //        oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                    //        // this is the data type ("t"), with CellValues.String ("str")
                    //        oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));


                    //        //oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
                    //        //oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnData.ToString() == null ? "" : arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnData.ToString()));

                    //        // this is for Cell
                    //        //oxw.WriteEndElement();


                    //    }

                    //    // this is for Row
                    //    //oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    //}

                    // this is for SheetData
                    //oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    //// this is for Worksheet
                    //oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    //oxw.Close();

                    //oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(xl.WorkbookPart);
                    //oxw.WriteStartElement(new Workbook());
                    //oxw.WriteStartElement(new Sheets());

                    //oxw.WriteElement(new Sheet()
                    //{
                    //    Name = "Sheet" + sheetnumber.ToString(),
                    //    SheetId = Convert.ToUInt32(sheetnumber),
                    //    Id = xl.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wsp)
                    //});

                    //// this is for Sheets
                    //oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    //// this is for Workbook
                    //oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    //oxw.Close();

                    xl.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                {
                    List<OpenXmlAttribute> oxa;
                    OpenXmlWriter oxw;

                    xl.AddWorkbookPart();
                    WorksheetPart wsp = xl.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

                    oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(wsp);
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

                    for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum <= arrExport.Count - 1; rowNum++)
                    {
                        int u = Convert.ToInt32(rowNum.ToString());
                        oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("r", null, "str"));

                        oxw.WriteStartElement(new Row(), oxa);
                        int NextPosition = 0;
                        for (int col = 0; col < arrExport[u].ColumnData.Count; col++)
                        {
                            if (!((col + 1) >= arrExport[u].ColumnData.Count - 1))
                            {
                                NextPosition = (arrExport[u].ColumnData[col + 1].ColumnNumber - arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnNumber);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                NextPosition = arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnNumber - 1;
                            }

                            for (int x = 0; x < NextPosition; x++)
                            {
                                oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                                // this is the data type ("t"), with CellValues.String ("str")
                                oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));

                                oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
                                oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(""));

                                // this is for Cell
                                oxw.WriteEndElement();
                            }
                            oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                            // this is the data type ("t"), with CellValues.String ("str")
                            oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));


                            oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
                            oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnData.ToString() == null ? "" : arrExport[u].ColumnData[col].ColumnData.ToString()));

                            // this is for Cell
                            oxw.WriteEndElement();


                        }

                        // this is for Row
                        oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    }

                    // this is for SheetData
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    // this is for Worksheet
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    oxw.Close();

                    oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(xl.WorkbookPart);
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Workbook());
                    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Sheets());

                    // you can use object initialisers like this only when the properties
                    // are actual properties. SDK classes sometimes have property-like properties
                    // but are actually classes. For example, the Cell class has the CellValue
                    // "property" but is actually a child class internally.
                    // If the properties correspond to actual XML attributes, then you're fine.
                    oxw.WriteElement(new Sheet()
                    {
                        Name = "Sheet" + sheetnumber.ToString(),
                        SheetId = Convert.ToUInt32(sheetnumber),
                        Id = xl.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wsp)
                    });

                    // this is for Sheets
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    // this is for Workbook
                    oxw.WriteEndElement();
                    oxw.Close();

                    xl.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Copy the file before modifying

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an instance of `Sheets`, append it to your `WorkbookPart`, and add the part to your `SpreadsheetDocument` then you can create your new sheets as `SheetData`

For example

```
WorkbookPart objWorkbookPart = objDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
objWorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
Sheets objSheets = new Sheets();
objWorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));
objWorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(objSheets);
```

create a `WorksheetPart`

```
WorksheetPart objWorksheetPart = objWorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
string strWorkSheetPartrId = objWorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(objWorksheetPart);
objWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();
```

then you append your `Sheet` to it

```
SheetData objSheetData = new SheetData();
Sheet objSheet = new Sheet() { Name = "Yoursheetname", SheetId = (UInt32Value)1U, Id = strWorkSheetPartrId };

objSheets.Append(objSheet);
```